# When deleting text from TextInputEditText - RecyclerView item positions are not updated android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-textinputlayout

i have a fragment with a RecyclerView and TextInputEditText (for searching through Firebase Database)

When I start writing some text to filter the `RecyclerView`, I get the correct result, however if I remove text from `TextInputEditText`, the positions of the elements are not updated. For example: I have a `RecyclerView` of 3 elements, I filter by name and `RecyclerView` shows me only the third element, then I delete all the text with the `TextInputEditText`, all elements are returned, but my third element has the position of the first element. How can i fix this problem?

My code and video below:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    setupPlacesAdapter()

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(requireContext())

    getPlaces()

    binding.searchBar.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, size: Int) {
            val query = binding.searchBar.text.toString().uppercase()

            if (query.isEmpty()) {
                getPlaces()
            } else {
                filterByName(query)
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun setupPlacesAdapter() {
    placeAdapter = PlaceAdapter()

    binding.rvPlaces.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
        requireContext(),
        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
        false
    )

    binding.rvPlaces.adapter = placeAdapter
}

private fun getPlaces() {
    val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Places")

    reference.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                val list = ArrayList<Place>()

                for (placeSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val place = placeSnapshot.getValue(Place::class.java)

                    list.add(place!!)
                }

                placeAdapter.submitList(list)
                placeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun filterByName(query: String) {
    Log.d("MyTag", "Filtered")
    val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("Places")
        .orderByChild("name")
        .startAt(query)
        .endAt(query + "\uf8ff")

    reference.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                val list = ArrayList<Place>()

                for (placeSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val place = placeSnapshot.getValue(Place::class.java)

                    list.add(place!!)
                }

                placeAdapter.submitList(list)
                placeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Demonstration of the problem itself on the video at the link: https://youtu.be/YlD9LTppC0s

Comment: >  all elements are returned, but my third element has the position of the first element,        

What do you mean by that. I see that the position of the items is the same when you delete the search query

Comment: You don't have to filter in the list items by calling the firebase again you can search for recyclerview filter to search in recycler view items

Comment: @georkost If you look at the video, then for 17 seconds I click on the third item in the `RecyclerView`, but I get information about the first. And I don't know how to fix it :(